# Use the triangle inequality to prove that $|x - 2z| < 11$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Additional INFO: x, y, z are real numbers that satisfy -3 < x - y< 3 and the distance between y and 2z is at most 8.

I am trying to prove this and what I have so far is:

- We WTS $|x - 2z| < 11$
- equivalent to $-11 < x - 2z < |x| - |2z|$
- proof: $-|x|≤ x ≤|x|$
- $-|2z|≤ 2z ≤ |2z|$
- thus $-|x| + (-|2z|) ≤ x - 2z ≤ |x| - |2z|$

Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: What do we know about $x$ and $z$? The inequality does not hold when $x=12$ and $z=0$...

Comment: @JalaAriya Welcome to Math SE. Your fourth point of - $-|2z|≤ 2z ≤ |2z|$ is correct, but you can't use this to get your next line of $-|x| + (-|2z|) ≤ x - 2z ≤ |x| - |2z|$ because you're multiplying the middle & right terms by $-1$. Instead, the correct result is $-|x| + (-|2z|) ≤ x + 2z ≤ |x| + |2z|$. As [Robert Z](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/299698/robert-z)'s comment states, it's not clear how $x$ and $z$ are supposed to relate to each other, so we can't easily help you to finish what you're trying to prove. Please update your question to give more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Uh... just do the triangle inequality.

$|x-2z| \le |x-y| + |y-2z| \le 3+8 = 11$

Answer (score 0):

$|x-2z|=|(x-y)+(y-2z)| \le |x-y|+|y-2z| <3+8=11.$